# GCC linker - how to extract .data .bss from custom input linker section

Tags: gcc, linker

I am working with embedded C code and trying to modify GCC linker script where I define my own section with initialized and uninitialized variables. By default all the variables fall under .data input sections or .bss section depending whether they are supposed to start initialized or not.

```
int var1;      // this will fall into .bss section
int var2 = 2;  // this will fall into .data section
```

Now I have created my own input section called .my_section, and placed these variables into it:

```
int var1 __attribute__((section(".my_section")));
int var2 __attribute__((section(".my_section"))) = 2;
```

How can I distinguish in the linker script initialized from uninitialized variables in .my_section, so later on in the startup code I would be able to set the RAM correctly for variables from this custom section? Is it possible to extract the .bss and .data 'sub-sections' from .my_section? Is this approach feasible at all?

Please keep in mind that I do not wish for variables from .my_section to fall into regular .data and .bss input sections. These are placed in regular RAM. .my_section is placed in ECC protected RAM, therefore a separation is required.

Kind regards.

Search over some forums, google, reading linker documentation.

Comment: Note that variables in static storage without explicit initializer ARE initialized (to zero) on startup. These usually go to `.bss`.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts That is true for a regular application that starts at main(). In case of embedded system my startup code runs before the main() and it decides on how RAM should get initialized. This startup code may/may not adhere to standard C expectations. Now I do want it to adhere to typical C expectations, therefore the question

Comment: There are no section flags for `.bss` (at least not in default GCC / Bnutils).  As you are putting all the stuff in the same input section, maybe the easiest solution is to treat bss like data, i.e. as if they has explicit initializers.

Comment: I thought about it, the problem is that these objects that do not require any special initialization will needlessly consume FLASH memory. I would prefer cleaner solution where linker figures out what is/isn't initialized and automatically allocates variables to specific areas. Suggested method is a workaround though.

Comment: I've seen solutions that do what you want but they required extending GCC and Binutils.

Comment: I would like to stick to generic GCC as is. I have a feeling that this method is not going to work... :/ Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: These extensions were not made for no reason... Maybe the simplest approach is to use different input sections for bss / non-bss. What also might work is to do a hack using tools like `nm` that shows symbol information and then transform the ELF somehow.